# Scroll down to page, scroll up to top system like on a MEGA.co.nz download page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

```
var pagestart = 0;
var currentlyat = pagestart;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    function scrollPageTo(a){
        if(a == 0){
    $('#top').show();
    $('#top').animate({
        top: 0
    }, 1000, function(event){
        $('#page').css('top', $(window).height()).hide();
    });
        }
        else
        {
    $('#page').hide();
    $('#page').animate({
        top: 0
    }, 1000, function(event){
        $('#top').css('top', $(window).height()).hide();
    });
        }
    }

    if(pagestart == 0){
        $('#top').css('height', $(window).height());
        $('#page').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#top').hide();
        $('#page').css('height', $(window).height());
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(currentlyat == 0){
    if(($(this).scrollTop() < lastScrollTop) && $(this).scrollTop() == 0){
        scrollPageTo(1);
    }
        }
        else
        {
    if(($(this).scrollTop() > lastScrollTop) && $(this).scrollTop() == 0){
        scrollPageTo(0);
    }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uZiDaXud/1/edit

What I'm trying to do is create sort of like the system the site MEGA.co.nz has, on for example [this](https://mega.co.nz/#!xhBwRTbY!NtatdA71IKCvXpw8k9lxDwrRR9k0S0uO18hJMdC90FM) page.

Basically two containers, wich hold two separate pages. One in `#top`, and the other one in `#page`. `pagestart` determines if it should start with `#top` or `#page`. `#top` always has the same height as the user's window (thus having no scrollbar). When you scroll down when `#top` is active, or click a link somewhere, `#top` will scroll up above the screen and `#page` will scroll up from the bottom. And when `#page` is active (which can be taller then the user's window), and you're on the top of the page and then still scroll up (or click a link), `#page` will scroll down below the screen and `#top` will scroll down from the top.

What this will result into is a page where when you scroll down, an animation starts which moves `#top` above the screen and brings up the `#page`, and then you'll be able to scroll normally. And when you're at the top of the page and you scroll up, `#top` will pop up again.

Hard to explain, so that's why I recommend clicking [this](https://mega.co.nz/#!xhBwRTbY!NtatdA71IKCvXpw8k9lxDwrRR9k0S0uO18hJMdC90FM) and seeing it as MEGA.co.nz has implemented it.

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/WQWyV/)

---

*Uses [jQuery mouse wheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

---

**HTML structure**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="splash">
        <div id="splash-footer">Show content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-header">Show splash</div>
        <div><!-- content here --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* css normalized */
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
}
#splash {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#cce;
    height:100%;
}
#splash-footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#content-header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
/* scroll events */
$("#splash").on("mousewheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
        $('#splash').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});
$("#content").on("mousewheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
        $('#splash').animate({
            height: '100%'
        }, 500);
    }
});

/* click events */
$("#splash-footer").on("click", function () {
    $('#splash').animate({
        height: 0
    }, 500);
});
$("#content-header").on("click", function () {
    $('#splash').animate({
        height: '100%'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing work. When I want to start on the page, instead of on the top, I can just set the height of `#splash` to 0, right?